# In JavaScript how to detect weather the type is Array or Object?

Tags: javascript, variable-types

I need to know how to check the variable if its an Array or its an Object

```
var arr = ['foo', 'bar'];
var obj = {
  0: 'foo',
  1: 'bar'
}

document.write('arr is an: ' + typeof arr + ', obj is an: ' + typeof obj)

// The result is always:
// arr is an: object, obj is an: object
```

Is there any way to tell the difference between the two types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.isArray(arr)` will return `true`.
`Array.isArray(obj)` will return `false`.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful